# I'd like to upgrade my MacBook Pro's RAM and hard drive. What brands are reliable?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, upgrade, memory, hardware-recommendation

I do heavy web development/web design and run my software on a MacBook Pro (Mid 2009) 2.8ghz model. I use Adobe products, run virtual machines in Parallels, have multiple browsers open, text editors and sometimes IDE's. That's how I typically use my machine.

I'd like to upgrade my RAM and possibly get a larger capacity hard drive, but I'm not sure what brands to buy.

From what I've read so far, it looks like Kingston HyperX KHX1600C9S3P1K2/8G is what I need. As for a hard drive I'm after something reliable. No nasty surprises a year from now.

I would really appreciate some advice as this is something I've delayed doing since I purchased my MacBook Pro.

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off topic, per the [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).

Comment: Some hardware recommendations are on-topic. http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/refining-policy-on-hardware-recommendations

Comment: I disagree, this question forces *subjectivity* and  *unspecific answers*. By what standards do we measure *reliable*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same to one of my old macs and opted for Crucial Memory and a Western Digital hard drive. Their still going strong and I've had absolutely no problems (and the WD drive is *really fast*)

Comment: £34.79 for crucials.. didn't expect the pack to be so cheap. If you was running a mbp do you remember the maximum sized harddrive it could take?

Comment: I do have a mbp, and I put a 500gb hard drive in, but I don't see why it couldn't go up to at least 750 (I'm not sure there is a limit, provided the connectors are right).

Comment: Second vote for Crucial when picking RAM, and WD has always been good with hard drives.

Answer (score 1):

## [OWC](http://macsales.com/)

I buy everything from these guys. They can get RAM and hard drives for just about any Mac and it's almost always within $5 of [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com/), without having to sort through their PC crap.

They sell exclusively Apple stuff and it's easy to find what you're looking for. Usually free or less than $3-5 shipping and it's super fast (even for the free/cheap shipping).

In your question, you mentioned that you don't want any nasty surprises down the road. If you really don't, then ***back up***. Know that every hard drive will eventually fail. Some will drop dead in a year, some will drop dead in 10 years. You just won't know until it happens, usually.

There are two best practices for avoiding catastrophic hard drive failure:

1. **BACK UP**.
   (can't stress this enough)
2. Buy quality hard drives from good companies. I, for instance, will not buy a hard drive from anyone but **Hitachi**. OWC sells hitachi hard drives. They're a little more expensive, but I've never had one die on me. That being said, I still **back up**.

Comment: I've lost quite important data in the past as well as a large music collection I spent a long time recording from vinyl onto my system and arranging into folders. Ever since then I've tried to avoid western digital drives even though many people recommend them. I always have time machine enabled as I can't take any chances this time round. I'll check out OWC thanks.

Comment: Good call. Yeah, I won't ever buy a Seagate or WD hard drive. They're awful. Good luck.

Comment: NewEgg have Mac section now for a lot of components. Not that OWC aren't good - just saying it's there if you want to look.